# Pandas replace function wrongly changes in all dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I use pandas replace function to replace a value. Please see the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'color' : pd.Series(['white', 'blue', 'orange']),
   'second_color': pd.Series(['white', 'black', 'blue']),
   'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df1)

df = df1
df['color'] = df['color'].replace('white','red')

print(df1)

print(df)
```

I intend to change a value in `df`, but why is the same value in `df1` also changed?

The code below is ok.

```
df=df.replace('white','red')
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.copy()`

```
df = df1.copy()
```

So the changes you do to `df` will not propagate to `df1`

Answer (score 2):

Because both are referencing the same data location.

When you do `df = df1` it does not create a new data frame it just set the reference of `df` to variable `df1`. Using `id()` you can see both referencing to the same address.

```
>>> df = df1
>>> id(df)
41633008
>>> id(df1)
41633008
```

To make a new copy you can use [`DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method

```
>>> df = df1.copy()
>>> id(df)
31533376
>>> id(df1)
41633008
```

Now you can see both referenced to different locations.

There is still much to learn about shallow copy and deep copy. Please read the document for more. - [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)